# mysql,update multiple rows through an ajax call with primary keys in an array 

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

An array containing  the primary key values of a mysql table  will be passed through an 
ajax call to a  php page and from the php page, rows with the primary keys in the array will be updated

js snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){


    var my_array=[1,2.,4,5,6];

    $.post("array_post.php",{

        my_array:my_array

        },function(response){

            alert(response);
            }

    );



    });


</script>
```

'id' is the primary key.
array_post.php has :

```
$my_array=$_POST['my_array'];

$sql="UPDATE my_table SET my_col=1 WHERE id IN ($my_array)";
```

Bu that shows error.

I need the solution.

Comment: something like : Sorry the update query could not be executed into table post_comment notification</br>You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Array' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to transform your array to a string:

```
$sql="UPDATE my_table SET my_col=1 WHERE id IN (" . implode(',', $my_array) . ")";
```

And, you should seriously validate your input, not just use $_POST

Comment: so, 'IN' key word searches in a comma separated string , not in an array, right?

Comment: Yeah, well, you just can't use an PHP array in an SQL String. It need to look like `IN (1,2,3)`.

Answer (score 1):

your array must be comma separated so use implode(",",$my_array) instead of using just $my_array

Comment: implode returns a string, not an array